# Wrong insert function overload is invoked in my custom std::vector implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have two conflicting function overload for insert in my own implementation of std::vector.

```
namespace PR {
template <typename T>
class vector {   
    ...
    // First insert function takes a value and inserts count copies at pos 
    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, size_t count, const T& value); 

    // Second insert function takes an iterator for the first and last element and inserts
    // it at pos. 
    template <typename input_iterator>
    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, input_iterator first,
                    input_iterator last);
    ...
}
```

Now if I do a function call like this:

```
    auto iter = vec1.insert(vec1.cbegin() + 1, 1, 4);
```

I get an error message like this:

```
/home/panky92/C++/ImplVector/./Vector.h:395:14:   required from ‘T* PR::vector<T>::insert(PR::vector<T>::const_iterator, input_iterator, input_iterator) [with input_iterator = int; T = int; PR::vector<T>::iterator = int*; PR::vector<T>::const_iterator = const int*]’
/home/panky92/C++/ImplVector/test/tests-main.cpp:211:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:377:57: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<int>’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::value_type _ValueTypeI;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:379:64: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<int>’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::iterator_category _Category;
```

It looks like it is calling the **second insert function** with iterator input instead of the first one, even though my intention was to call the first one with this function call. This **function call worked** before I **included** the **second overload function**.

The calls below are working as expected:

```
    PR::vector<std::string> strvec{"Hello", "World", "!!"};

    auto iter = strvec.insert(strvec.cbegin() + 1, 2, "C++"); // calls the first insert function

    PR::vector<int> vec1{1, 2, 3};
    PR::vector<int> vec2{1, 2, 3};

    auto iter1 = vec1.insert(vec1.cbegin() + 1, vec2.begin(), vec2.end()); // calls the second insert function
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The Dupe is for a constructor but the exact same technique can be applied to member functions as well.

Comment: You'll also want to use `std::input_iterator_tag` instead of `std::random_access_iterator_tag` for the `iterator_category`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comments. I am pretty new to SFINAE. It took me sometime to understand the concept and now my overload is working perfectly. But for me it works with std::random_access_iterator_tag as I am using only a pointer and not using any allocator types for my vector implementation.